# Замена содержимого в XML в среде MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Коллеги, есть такая задача по замене значений в поле data, где сообственно сам XML документ.
Необходимо, чтобы производилась замена @yandex.ru на @mail.ru (логин,email) значения по всем записям. Записей в таблице более 100. Каким образом реализовать проход по всем записям с последовательной заменой значений?

Структура таблицы:

```
collaborator (id int, data xml)
```

Пример содержимого XML документа:

```
<collaborator>
<id>5759501959199724993</id>
<lastname>Рязанцев</lastname>
<firstname>Дмитрий</firstname>
<middlename>Александрович</middlename>
<phone>499-0000000</phone>
<email>ryazancevda@mail.ru</email>
<login>ryazancevda@mail.ru</login>
</collaborator>
```

Запрос:

```
declare @xml xml 
select @xml=data from collaborator
declare @email varchar(80)
declare @login varchar(80)

begin
update collaborator
    set @email = @xml.value('(/collaborator/email)[1]', 'varchar(80)')
    set @email = replace(@email, 'yandex.ru', 'mail.ru')
    set @xml.modify('
       replace value of (/collaborator/email/text())[1]
       with sql:variable("@email")
   ')

    set @login = @xml.value('(/collaborator/login)[1]', 'varchar(80)')
    set @login = replace(@login, 'yandex.ru', 'mail.ru')
    set @xml.modify('
       replace value of (/collaborator/login/text())[1]
       with sql:variable("@login")
   ')

 end
select @xml;
```

Comment: В функции `replace` нужно поменять местами яндекс и мейл. Остальное верно.

Comment: не совсем, это просто пример xml документа, в поле data их множество, есть проблема, происходит замена только одного значения, то есть одной строчки в таблице collaborator.

Answer (score 2):

Я думал, думал... Придумал такое:

```
update collaborator
set data.modify('   
    replace value of (/collaborator/email/text())[1]
    with concat(
        substring(
            (/collaborator/email/text())[1],
            1,
            string-length((/collaborator/email/text())[1]) - string-length("mail.ru")),
        "yandex.ru")
')
where data.exist('/collaborator/email/text()[contains(., "mail.ru")]') = 1


update collaborator
set data.modify('   
    replace value of (/collaborator/login/text())[1]
    with concat(
        substring(
            (/collaborator/login/text())[1],
            1,
            string-length((/collaborator/login/text())[1]) - string-length("mail.ru")),
        "yandex.ru")
')
where data.exist('/collaborator/login/text()[contains(., "mail.ru")]') = 1
```

Получается два запроса. Это лучшее, что удалось придумать.

Обновить за раз можно только одну строку.

К тому же [набор функций XQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) весьма ограничен, поэтому пришлось изобретать такую сложную конструкцию с использованием `concat/substring/string-length`.

---

Если точно известно, что все логины и емейлы заканчиваются на "mail.ru", то можно убрать условие `where data.exist`.

В коде неоднократно повторяются однотипные конструкции вида `(/collaborator/login/text())[1]`, что весьма громоздко. Не знаю, может есть способ использовать переменную `let $login := ...` и далее её подставлять?

Answer (score 1):

Если XML имеет такую простую структуру, то можно обойтись одним `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE t
SET
    t.data = data.query('
        element collaborator
        {
            for $a in (/collaborator/*)
            return
                if (local-name($a) = "email")
                then element email { text { sql:column("d2.email") } }
                else if (local-name($a) = "login")
                then element login { text { sql:column("d2.login") } }
                else $a
        }
    ')
FROM
    collaborator t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            email = t.data.value('(/collaborator/email/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(400)'),
            login = t.data.value('(/collaborator/login/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(400)')
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            email = REPLACE(d.email, N'@mail.ru', N'@yandex.ru'),
            login = REPLACE(d.login, N'@mail.ru', N'@yandex.ru')
    ) d2
```

т.е. XML каждой строки данных пересобирается с помощью [FLWOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery), но в элементах *email* и *login* значения заменяются выражениями возвращаемыми `REPLACE`.