# Обновление узлов в XML через CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Допустим, есть таблица и в ней есть поле с XML.

В каждом xml есть множество узлов root/Row. Если этот узел равен определенному значению, то мне нужно сделать replace value of.

Проблема в том, что replace value of выполняется только на 1 узле за раз=> нужно делать явный цикл пока exist('бла бла бла')=1.

Собственно вопрос, а можно ли это сделать лаконичной CTEшкой, без явного цикла

Comment: А реальный xml сложнее, или там в самом деле `root/row`? Если xml несложный, то можно без циклов и без cte (наподобие [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903992/193999)).

Comment: @i-one ничего себе. В XML циклы есть? А где можно найти богатые примеры?

Comment: Точнее сказать в _XQuery_, в [доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery) есть примеры, вообще всё что есть в разделе [XQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server) можно просмотреть.

Comment: @i-one, а не покатит... У меня 2008 сервер...

Comment: Да, в документации написано _"начиная с версии 2012"_, но это не соответствует действительности, XQuery поддерживается вроде бы с 2005 (по крайней мере в 2008 работает точно). И, по-моему, с тех пор никаких новых фич в реализацию XQuery в SqlServer не добавлялось.